# How to use "Filter" method in AngleSharp?

Tags: c#, filter, anglesharp

I tryed to use filter like this:

```cs
var table = HTML.QuerySelector(".table>tbody");
var rows = table.QuerySelectorAll<IHtmlAnchorElement>("tr").Filter("td>div>input[value*=\"LT\"]");
```

But it just gave me an empty collection. I expected it chooses all tr where exist "td>div>input[value*="LT"]". I checked with browser that there's no css-selector mistakes: I run this code in the console and it worked as expected:

```js
[...document.querySelector(".table>tbody").querySelectorAll("tr")].filter((tr) => tr.querySelector('td>div>input[value*="PC"]'));
```